# Getting Error in JSON at position 0 (Duplicated)

Tags: json, reactjs

I having problem getting the users data I watching youtube ReactJS PHP Token Based Restful API User Authentication and I followed his tutorial but i got this error.

In my console i got this error.

> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

**I created UserData.js and import this UserData.js to my login page**

**import {UserData} from './UserData';**

```
    export function UserData(type, users_data) {
    let BaseUrl = 'http://localhost:8000/api/login_restful/';

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        fetch(BaseUrl+type, {
            method: 'post',
            body: JSON.stringify(users_data),
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(function (response){
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((res) => {
            resolve(res)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
        });
    })
}
```

**This is my button handleSubmit:**

```
handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    UserData('login',this.state).then(response => {
        let result = response;
        console.log(result);
    })


}
```

**In my Network:**

[image: Network Image]

**Response:**
[image: Response Image]

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the error message corresponds to what you get from Google Chrome when you run JSON.parse('<...'). I believe the response body is actually HTML.

"SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

I would suggest that you add to your logging.

```
        fetch(BaseUrl+type, {
        method: 'post',
        body: JSON.stringify(users_data),
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'),
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
    })
    .then(function (response){
        console.log('res', response);
        return response.json();
    })
    .then((res) => {
        resolve(res)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        reject(error);
    });
```

Looking at the actual xhr (XMLHttpRequest) properties to learn more about the response. Try adding console.warn(xhr.responseText) and you will most likely see the HTML that is being received.

Comment: I add this console.log('res', response); but the error comes from my console is still same.

Comment: just for check is your repsonse correct JSON format or HTML

Comment: Could you add response content in question ?

Comment: I add the response

Comment: seem problem with response body

Comment: what's the problem?